# PopOver view controller covers full screen

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code for PopOver. I have two View controllers. I am presenting the PopOver in Messaging View controller and the view controller that need to be piped is PreferencesView controller. Storyboard Id is also same Preferences View controller. The popOver is success but always covers the full screen. Even though **UIModalPresentationStyle.None**. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 func optionClicked(sender:UIBarButtonItem)
{
    print(")show set preference and set reminder option")


    let preferenceAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Set preferences", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        self.optionChoosed(true)
        }
    let reminderAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Set reminder", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        self.optionChoosed(false)
    }
    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: kAlertTitle, message: "What you want to do?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(preferenceAction)
    actionSheetController.addAction(reminderAction)
    actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func optionChoosed(isSetPreference:Bool)
{


    if(isSetPreference)
    {
    print("Set preference")

        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Messaging", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PreferencesViewController") as! PreferencesViewController
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController!
        popover.barButtonItem?.action = "isSetPreference"
        popover.delegate = self
        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)


    }

    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None

    }
    func dismiss() {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: where are calling from optionChoosed ? and are presenting PopOver when you click on bar button?

Comment: yes i have two actions in bar buttons

Comment: can you show complete code?

Comment: of what code shall i post

Comment: i meant where are calling from optionChoosed? show code from where you calling optionChoosed.

Comment: ok i have edited it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129016/discussion-between-sahil-and-niroj-thapa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are performing segue from storyboard. if you are doing so remove segue from storyboard and create an action for bar button item and put this code there.

```
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Messaging", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PreferencesViewController") as! PreferencesViewController
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController!
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    popover.barButtonItem = sender as? UIBarButtonItem
    popover.delegate = self
    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: you have to pass it in function.   self.optionChoosed(true,sender) and function signature  func optionChoosed(isSetPreference:Bool, sender: UIBarButtonItem)

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton _viewForPresenting]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff933a29f60'
ERROR crashes the app

Answer (score 2):

Implement this function where you call the popover

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
```

I hope it will help

Comment: can you add also popover.sourceView = base and popover.sourceRect = base.bounds

Comment: if you use button change them like this

Comment: popover.sourceView = button and popover.sourceRect = button.bounds